# Why Next.js doesn't recognize TS code in .tsx and .ts files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Pages without declared interface opens fine

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the content of `ISignView`?

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: export default interface ISignView extends React.PropsWithChildren {
  isSignUp?: boolean;
  handleSubmit: () => void;
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to typecast in correct way
`as ISignView` instead of `: ISignView`